# alphaArc length reparameterization of a parametric curve represented as an expression in R

Tags: r, function, expression

I have been struggling for quite a while now with trying to implement pracma's arclength() function. The two errors I am getting based on what ive tried so far are:

```
Error in arclength(f, t1, t2) : 
  Argument 'f' must be a parametrized function.
```

or

```
Error in arclength(f, t1, t2) : 
  Argument 'f' must be a vectorized function.
```

I have a parametric curve defined as a vector of 3 expressions. The curve is an ellipse lying on the plane z=-1 given by:

```
inputCurve = expression(0.5*cos(t), sin(t),-1)
```

My code which was taken directly from the documentation is here. The code ideally should reparametrize the inputCurve with respect to arcLength:

```
arcLengthUtil$arcLengthParametrize <- function(inputCurve){
  
  
  
  f <- function(t) c(eval(quote(inputCurve)))
  
  
  t1<-0; t2<- 2*pi
  a<-0;b<-arclength(f,t1,t2)$length
  
  fParam <-function(s){
    fct <- function(u) arclength(f,a,u)$length -s
    urt<- uniroot(fct, c(a, 2*pi))
    urt$root
  }
 

  return(fParam)
}
```

I am passing the expression into f as a vector, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. From my understanding eval() should return an expression that can be called within f. I have tried using the Vectorize() function on f and then passing it to arcLength(), but received the error that 'f' must be a parametrized function. I feel like this is a fairly straightforward problem, but if anyone could offer some advice it would be much appreciated. Thank you

```
##  Example: parametrized 3D-curve with t in 0..3*pi
f <- function(t) c(sin(2*t), cos(t), t)
arclength(f, 0, 3*pi)
```

This is one of the examples from the documentation, I am just wondering how I can pass my input curve defined by the vector of expressions into my function 'f' since I need the declaration of the curve to be in the form stated above.

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you following? I'm not sure I understand what you expect to happen when you call your `f` function. It seems like since you are eval-ing a list of expressions the only return value is the last expression so you just get `-1` always. And you just get a single value returned, not a vector the length of `t` which was passed in so the function is not properly vectorized (with a vectorized function, if you pass in a vector of `n` elements, you expect to get a vector of `n` elements in returned)

Comment: I updated my question which shows an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I really just need to know how to pass my expression into 'f' in the correct form as above shown above.

Comment: Why are you trying to deconstruct the terms into a vector of expressions? Why don't you just pass in a function? Are you really doing this all just to avoid typing `function(t)`? How exactly do you want to pass parameters to `arcLengthUtil$arcLengthParametrize()`?

Comment: Maybe you want `inputCurve = expression(c(0.5*cos(t), sin(t),-1))`, but it still seems to me it would be much easier to just pass along a proper (possibly anonymous) function that an expression vector.

Comment: All of my input is stored in a matrix of vector expressions defining the parametric curves. So it would be optimal to not have to change the format of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some wonky code but this works if you need to use a vector of expressions.

```
f <- eval(parse(text=paste0("function(t) c(t*0+",paste(inputCurve,collapse=",t*0+"),")")))
```

This creates a function f for use in the `arclength` function with the same syntax as in the question. The `t*0+` portion of the `collapse` argument is required for f to return a vector the same length as the input when not all of the expressions contain a variable input.

Comment: I am getting the same error as before i.e Argument 'f' must be a vectorized function.

Comment: Ah yes, in the previous orientation the last element didn't get t*0 added, and it was the only one that needed it. I changed the ordering of the comma in the collapse argument to fix it for this case, but to account for cases in which the first element of the vector is a constant, you need to add t*0 to the first element, so I've also added that.